How to use geotools to load tif files and generate images using WMS like GeoServer
I want to use geotools to write code to implement geoserver loading tif files to implement wms services. After loading geotools, I performed wms output, but my code encountered two problems: the first problem is that when the spatial reference system of the tif file is not 3857 or 4326, the generated slice combination will be offset; the second problem is that when the spatial reference system of the tif file is not 3857 or 4326, After I narrow down the range, some pictures outside the tif will be black instead of the transparent color I expected.
My core code is as follows:
                    public BufferedImage getBufferedImage() {    
            File geoTifFile = new File("D:\\test.tif");
                        GeoTiffReader reader = new GeoTiffReader(geoTifFile);
                        GridCoverage2D coverage = reader.read(null);
            // Convert coordinate points, get envelope
                        CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = coverage.getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
                        ProjCoordinate[] sourceCoords = new ProjCoordinate[]{
                                new ProjCoordinate(x1, y1),
                                new ProjCoordinate(x2, y1),
                                new ProjCoordinate(x2, y2),
                                new ProjCoordinate(x1, y2)
                        };

                        ProjCoordinate[] targetCoords = new ProjCoordinate[4];
                        CRSFactory crsFactory = new CRSFactory();
                        String crs = "EPSG:" + new ArrayList<>(targetCRS.getIdentifiers()).get(0).getCode();
                        CoordinateTransformFactory ctf = new CoordinateTransformFactory();
                        CoordinateTransform transform = ctf.createTransform(crsFactory.createFromName("EPSG:3857"), crsFactory.createFromName(crs));
                        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                            targetCoords[j] = new ProjCoordinate();

                            ProjCoordinate src = new ProjCoordinate(sourceCoords[j].x, sourceCoords[j].y);

                            transform.transform(src, targetCoords[j]);
                        }
                        
                        double xMin = targetCoords[0].x;
                        double yMin = targetCoords[0].y;
                        double xMax = targetCoords[2].x;
                        double yMax = targetCoords[2].y;

                        Envelope guassEnvelope = new Envelope(xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax);

                        ReferencedEnvelope cropEnvelope = new ReferencedEnvelope(guassEnvelope.getMinX(), guassEnvelope.getMaxX(),
                                guassEnvelope.getMinY(), guassEnvelope.getMaxY(), targetCRS);

                        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
                        rectangle.width = width;
                        rectangle.height = height;

                        AffineTransform worldToScreen = RendererUtilities.worldToScreenTransform(cropEnvelope, rectangle);
                        InterpolationNearest nearest = new InterpolationNearest();
                        RenderingHints hints = new RenderingHints(JAI.KEY_INTERPOLATION, nearest);

                        GridCoverageRenderer gcr = new GridCoverageRenderer(coverage.getCoordinateReferenceSystem2D(), cropEnvelope, rectangle, worldToScreen, hints);
                        gcr.setAdvancedProjectionHandlingEnabled(true);
                        gcr.setWrapEnabled(true);

                        RasterSymbolizerImpl symbolizer = new RasterSymbolizerImpl();
                        RenderedImage renderedImage = gcr.renderImage(reader, null, symbolizer, nearest, null, width, height);
                        if (renderedImage == null) {
                            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                            Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics();
                            graphics.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
                            graphics.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
                            graphics.dispose();
                            return image;
                        }

                        ImageWorker imageWorker = new ImageWorker(renderedImage);
                        ImageLayout imageLayout = new ImageLayout(0, 0, width, height, 0,
                                0, width, height, null, null);
                        imageWorker.setRenderingHint(JAI.KEY_IMAGE_LAYOUT, imageLayout);
                        imageWorker.setBackground(null);

                        RenderedImage[] array = new RenderedImage[]{renderedImage};
                        imageWorker.mosaic(array, MosaicDescriptor.MOSAIC_TYPE_OVERLAY, null, null, null, null);

                        imageWorker.makeColorTransparent(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));

                        return imageWorker.getBufferedImage();
                    }

There are two problems with the code drawing：
1.The entire image range will be filled with white, and I want transparency (consistent with geoserver).
Contains white filling
2.256*256 small size superposition will cause offset.
256*256 offset

I tried the methods by geotools guid and the methods for similar problems(https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/449100/create-a-256x256px-tile-with-geotools-like-geoserver), but none of them could completely solve my problem. Thank you for your help.

I'd look at the GeoServer code to see how they do it.

@lan Turton, Thank you very much for your suggestion. I am trying to read the source code of geoserver, but it is a bit difficult for me, which is why I raised this question. But reading the source code seems to be the ultimate solution, and I will continue to try. Do you have any information on this? Thank you for your answer.

really the question is why would you spend the time doing this in your own code when there are many existing solutions to use directly

@lan Turton, you are right. I am currently trying to find the answer from the geoserver source code.  When I find the answeer from the source code,  I will end this question. Thank you for you answer and have a nice day.
